# Netlify Lambda GraphQL importModuleError

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lambda, graphql, netlify

I've been trying for a while to figure out why this build keeps failing on serving this GraphQL endpoint.

This is the error I get when I try to access my Netlify Lambda Function of my GraphQL Endpoint.
https://grumble2.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/graphql

I'm not sure but seems that Netlify Lambda/Functions is struggling to serve the endpoint on a server and at this stage I'm no longer sure why. Is it babel related, is down to the webpack config or is it a Netlify Lambda configuration I've missed?

```html
{
   "errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError",
   "errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-lambda'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/bundle/serve.js\n- /var/task/graphql.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
   "trace":[
      "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-lambda'",
      "Require stack:",
      "- /var/task/bundle/serve.js",
      "- /var/task/graphql.js",
      "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
      "- /var/runtime/index.js",
      "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
      "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
      "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
      "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)",
      "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)",
      "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)",
      "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)",
      "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)",
      "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47"
   ]
}
```

I've got my functions folder in the root

```
/functions
|-/bundle (graphql files from src)
|-package.json
|-graphql.js
```

My Netlify.toml file

```
[build]
command = "npm run build && npm run bundle && npm run build:lambda"
base = ""
functions = "functions"
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

My root `package.json` scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node --experimental-modules ./src/graphql/index.js",
    "start": "HTTPS=true webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack",
    "bundle": "cpx \"src/graphql/**/*\" \"functions/bundle\"",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "jest": "jest",
    "jest:watch": "jest --watch",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "eslint:global": "eslint src -c src/.eslintrc.js --ext .js,.jsx,.tsx,.ts",
    "eslint:global:fix": "eslint --fix src -c src/.eslintrc.js --ext .js,.jsx,.tsx,.ts",
    "start:lambda": "netlify-lambda serve src/graphql",
    "build:lambda": "netlify-lambda build src/graphql --config webpack.config.js"
  },
```

This is the feature branch of the repo with the rest of the files
https://github.com/hghazni/Grumble/tree/netlify/lambda-graphql-server

If somebody has any idea why this is struggling to serve, I'd be greatly appreciative!

Comment: Just making sure, you npm install apollo-server-lambda? I see that you are correctly referencing it

Comment: Hey @RazRonen just double checked and it's definitely installed and included in both `package.json` files